# Scaffolding Idenitiy in ASP.NET Core error

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am trying to scaffold a new Identity into an ASP.NET project but i keep getting the following error :

> There was an Error running the selected code generator : 'There was an
>   error running the template
>   C:\Users***.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.web.codegenerators.mvc\3.0.0\Templates\IdentityVersioned\Bootstrap3\Pages\Account\Account.ConfirmEmailChange.cs.cshtml:
>   Template Processing Failed: The explicit expression block is missing a
>   closing ")" character. Make sure you have a matching ")" character for
>   all the "(" characters within this block,and that none of the ")"
>   characters are being interpreted as markup. The explicit expression
>   block is missing a closing ")" characters within this block, and that
>   none of the ")" characters are being interpreted as markup.'

I am using .NET CORE 3 and VS2019

Comment: Hi, how did you fix this error?

Comment: I did not fix it , I created a new project and made sure all packages up to date and stable and it worked .

Comment: Ok. I deleted the entire Templates folder and it seems to work. I am not using any part of Account.

Answer (score 3):

you can fix the template there are some ) missing.
The template file is specified in the error. (C:\Users***.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.web.codegenerators.mvc\3.0.0\Templates\IdentityVersioned\Bootstrap3\Pages\Account\Account.ConfirmEmailChange.cs.cshtml)

```
   private readonly UserManager<@(Model.UserClass)> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<@(Model.UserClass)> _signInManager;

    public ConfirmEmailChangeModel(UserManager<@(Model.UserClass)> userManager, SignInManager<@(Model.UserClass)> signInManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to be the solution. Also, should we really be messing with packages